# for loop - "Unreachable code detected" - Test

Tags: c#, object, for-loop, methods, tdd

I have the following test which needs to pass:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldRepeatANumberOfTimes()
{
    Simon simon = new Simon();
    Assert.AreEqual("hello hello hello", simon.Repeat("hello", 3)); 
    //So if parameter 3 was to be exchanged with 7, it would write "hello" seven times in one sentence.
}
```

For this assignment, I thought that a for loop would be a natural solution. So I tried this:

```
internal object Repeat(string v1, int v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v2; i++)
    {
        return "hello ";
    }

    return v1;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Unreachable code detected.

Specifically, the `i` in `i++` has an "error line" under it. Anybody able to spot what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well a function returns after the first `return` statement...

Comment: You're misunderstanding how `return` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work

```
internal object Repeat(string v1, int v2)
{
    var str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < v2; i++)
    {
        str += " " + v1;
    }

    return str.Trim();
```

}

Comment: `str` should start with the empty string, or `i` with 1.

Comment: To be honest I do not fully understand what function should do. It should add "hello" v2 times to v1 or it should return v1 repeated v2 times?

Comment: there is a test above that shows the expected output.

Comment: Updated. My fault.

Comment: @thesystem May you explain how it doesn't work ? What is returned by it ? What did you expect to return ?

Comment: @Youssef13 It worked, I have made an error at some point. Sorry about that and thanks

Comment: @Valerii I must have made some mistake at some point, because it ended up working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

After first iteration (`i=0`) your method is returning `return "hello ";` and so the `i++` is never executed. Also you will not be able to reach the line `return v1` because you have already returned something else. It seems you want to return (`hello` v2 times + `v1`), so your code should be something like this (note to the [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) usage):

```
internal IEnumerable<string> Repeat(string v1, int v2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v2; i++)
    {
        yield return "hello ";
    }

    yield return v1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to reach the line 'return v1' because you have the line 'return "hello"' in your for loop. Thus, your program exits in the for loop.

Comment: `return v1` is reachable. When `v2` is `0`, then loop never run.

Answer (score 1):

As you are **always** returning something during the first iteration, you only ever **run the loop once**. Therefore the `i++` in your for loop never executes.

Also, as Devin Liu correctly noted, returning something from inside the loop also renders the `return v1` from outside unreachable as you are (again always) returning something before.

Comment: There are not first iteration of loop, when `v2` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have more problems than that error:

Inside your loop, you always return "hello ", regardless of v1.

You return `"hello "` on your FIRST iteration, therefore it will never reah the `return v1;` line

If you pass 0 as the second parameter, it would still return v1 once (from the last return call).

Even after you fix that function, if you call it as `simon.Repeat("hello", 3)`, the result would be `"hellohellohello"`.

You can fix the function rewriting as:

```
    String reps = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < v2; i++)
    {
        reps = string.Concat(reps, v1);
    }

    return reps;
```

And your test as:

```
    Assert.AreEqual("hellohellohello", simon.Repeat("hello", 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, your function will always end up to this line

```
return "hello ";
```

To repeat your string, you can use something like this without any kind of looping.

```
return string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Repeat("Hello", 2));
```

Just put this single line inside your function and replace `Hello` and `2` with your parameters

Answer (score 1):

This method will return a string rather than a list of and add in the correct amount of spaces since the test case does not have a trailing space.

```
internal object Repeat(string v1, int v2)
{

    var output = string.empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < v2; i++)
    {
        output += v1;
        if(i <= v2-1)
        {
            output += " ";
        }
    }

    return output ;
}
```

A few other ways I'd recommend this:
If you think you will be building very large strings I suggest using StringBuilder instead, I did not just to write this as fast as possible.
You could also remove the trailing space at the end of the loop, I just prefer not to add it from the start.